# php count values column

Tags: php, pdo, count

i want to count the values column by users id

ex : i want to count values in mark column where id =1
means (30+70+30) how can do this after get the mark of users in sql code

database example

```
id         mark       user_id
-----      ----       -------- 
1          30         1
2          60         3
3          70         1
4          10         2
5          30         1
```

My Code

```
<?php 

$mark = $DB_con->prepare("SELECT id,mark,user_id FROM `tablename` WHER user_id=".$userRow['id']."");
$mark->execute();
foreach($mark->fetchAll() as $mar){
     echo count($mar['mark']);  
}

?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe something like this;

```
<?php 

$mark = $DB_con->prepare("SELECT id, mark, user_id FROM `tablename` WHERE user_id=$userRow['id']");
$mark->execute();
$total = 0;
foreach($mark->fetchAll() as $mar){
     $total += $mar['mark'];  
}
echo $total;

?>
```

Answer (score 2):

Why not something like

```
$mark = $DB_con->prepare("
SELECT sum(mark) 
FROM   `tablename` 
WHERE  user_id = ?");
$mark->bindParam(1, $userrow['id'], PDO::PARAM_INT);
```

As an aside, you should probably be using bindParam if you're getting that userid from a client, so that you're not vulnerable to sql injection.

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php 

$mark = $DB_con->prepare("SELECT id,mark,user_id FROM `tablename` WHER     user_id=".$userRow['id']."");
 $mark->execute();
 $counter = 0; // <-- THIS -----------
 foreach($mark->fetchAll() as $mar){
     echo count($mar['mark']); 
     $counter += $mar['mark']; // <-- THIS ----------

 }

echo $counter;

?>
```

*Also missing an E from the 'WHERE' in the above statement.